# Representing a group with a 3D polyhedron?

Tags: group-theory, visualization

I'm reading ["From Spinors to Quantum Mechanics" by Gerrit Coddens](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1783266368). In Chapter 2.9 he shows diagrams representing two different groups as nodes and edges making up a polyhedron in 3D space.

First he shows the Icosahedral group $Y$ as being represented by a truncated icosahedron.

Then he shows the symmetric group $S_4$ represented as a truncated cuboctahedron.

Unfortunately I wasn't able to follow his description of how these pictures were generated. My best understanding is something like this. The rotations and reflections that are symmetries of the icosahedron are the elements of the icosahedral group $Y$. These can be thought of as operators that act on points in 3D space. The idea is something about picking a point in 3D space to represent the identity. Then applying the group elements of $Y$ to this point and marking those as new points in the 3D space. This makes some sense to me. But I don't understand which nodes in the new picture get edges between them.

For $S_4$ I'm totally lost. We can pick a point in 3D space to represent the identity element of the group. But elements of $S_4$ don't act on vectors in 3D space, so I don't know how to get new points from old points.

- Can someone explain what is going on in these examples to me?
- Or could someone give me keywords to search so I could research more about this type of graphical representation of groups?
- Can any group be represented in 3D space in this way?

Comment: The keyword is "Cayley graph"

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.

Comment: @MarkS. I don't think so, seeing as $S_4$ has 24 elements while the cuboctahedron has only 12 vertices. It is simply that the cuboctahedron (or cube, or octahedron) has a group of rotational symmetries that is isomorphic to $S_4$. The cuboctahedron may be a nicer illustration of those symmetries than the cube or octahedron because it has 24 edges, and you can pick any one edge as reference and the 24 symmetries map that reference edge to the 24 edges. On the other hand you could split the faces of a cube into quarters and illustrate it just the same with those.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis sorry, it's a *truncated* cuboctahedron with 24 vertices. I'll fix that in the question. Does that change your comment that "Cayley graph" Is probably what is being discussed in the book?

Comment: Ok, so it seems in the Cayley graph each group element is represented by a vertex and two vertices share an edge if they are connected by one the elements from the specified set of generators chosen for this depiction. For a finite group I guess the Cayley graph will always "close back in" on itself. In some cases I guess the closed surface can be depicted in 3D?

Comment: I have a web page about [Cayley graphs](https://www.jaapsch.net/puzzles/cayley.htm) in the context of permutation puzzles that you may find helpful. Yes, only some simple cases have a useful 3d visualisation, though obviously all graphs can be embedded in 3d just like they can be drawn in 2D on paper.

Comment: Aaah, @JaapScherphuis, I recognize your name from my cubing days :). thank you for the link! I think what I was missing in the original reference was the point that the edges of the graph correspond to actions of a select set of generators, not arbitrary actions of any group element.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, the graphs in question in the text are indeed [Cayley graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley_graph) of the corresponding groups. A Cayley graph is generated by (1) identifying each element of the group with a vertex (2) identifying a [generating set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_set_of_a_group) for the group and (3) for each element $g$ and each element $s$ of the generating set, include an edge between the vertices representing $g$ and $gs$.

There's probably exact details I'm missing here about directed edges, colors, etc., but these details don't seem important for the "From Spinors to Quantum Mechanics" section so I haven't gone into that level of detail yet.

Not all groups can be represented *nicely* in 3D this way. i.e. as simple polyhedra with non-intersecting faces and edges.